# Problems running DPDK KNI example

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

I'm new to DPDK. I'm trying to learn about KNI. I compiled and fired up the KNI example provided with the library.

- I used the ifconfig commands to bring up the vEth interfaces that spin up corresponding to each port and assign ipaddress and netmasks to them.
- I tried to ping and hping (tcp ping) other machines on the same network. Through tcpdump, I can see that the KNI interfaces send out the right frames but don't seem to be receiving anything.
- I don't see any errors in dmesg or the console running the KNI test script.
- I proceeded to try and debug by printing out mbufs entries. The KNI Rx doesn't seem find anything in the ring buffer corresponding to the Eth port which is supposed to receive the data/frames. However, the ifconfig messages do show up on the buffers and are accordingly acted upon by the kernel.

It would be very helpful if someone can advise me on how to move forward with this and get this to work as it is supposed to. I have been spinning my wheels on this for a while. I have tried this on both VMs and physical machine with multiple network interfaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use e1000 emulated nic for VM. It will work as expected.